# Website doesn't display in Opera and Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, opera

I know this question has been asked but I haven't found the answer to my question.

My website, http://www.rastorant.com isn't displaying in Opera and Firefox, the css and some of the html is just not there for some reason. I have validated the site multiple times and it works perfectly in Safari, Chrome and IE. The site's in Bulgarian but it's very simple.

There are six cards that link to the rest of the site, they go in this order:

Gallery, Menu, Contact info,
Birthdays, Events, New Years.

The html is very short if you look at the source and the css is the same across all pages.

Comment: There are these following errors in firefox

`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.rastorant.com/stylesheets%5Cstyle.css"

styles...yle.css

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.rastorant.com/pictures%5Cheader%5Ctest2.jpg"

pictur...st2.jpg

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.rastorant.com/pictures%5Cheader%5Ctest1.jpg"`

Comment: I've fixed it thanks to Musa but thank you as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `\` in your urls, which causes 404s in firefox. Use `/` instead.

e.g use

```
<link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" style="text/css">
```

instead of

```
<link href="stylesheets\style.css" rel="stylesheet" style="text/css">
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I did that.